# I need to add a new route (terminal) and have my c++ server go through it

Tags: command-line, 16.04, routing, ifconfig, virtual-console

I am on a Ubuntu VM version 16.04.

I need to add a new route in terminal and have my c++ server application go through it.

I tried figuring this out, but I'm a beginner and am having trouble.

I need to use the route command and (maybe)ifconfig.

I was also told this can be accomplished with 1 line and something of the lines of this: 
[route add -net 192.168.98.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.99.1](http://linux-ip.net/html/basic-changing.html)

Comment: You will need to give a little more context. Why does your server need a new route? To where, in terms of network ranges and interfaces?

Comment: I was just told this can be accomplished in 1 line . It needs to have an end point. The idea is that a client can go to the ip address and get the result.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A friend helped me figure it out:

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.0.2/32 gw 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

Obviously, change the IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run commands as root or with sudo.
Use ip route istead:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.98.0/24 via 192.168.99.1
```

NOTE: The IP 192.168.99.1 needs to be direct connected to your PC, in other words you need to have and IP address from that subnetclass asignet to an local network interface.

Check your IP address via command `ifconfig | grep "inet "` and check if you have and IP from that subnet you wish to add

Use `ip route list` to list your current routes and check if your new route have been added.